Deployment of Google Cloud Run Function v2 - trigger not invoked / run
I am migrating my Google Cloud Run Functions from v1 and Node 12 to v2 and Node 20.
So far I have upgraded onSchedule and onMessagePublished triggers with no problem.
When trying to deploy Realtime database triggers and using eventarc things seem to break.
This is my code for a test function:
const { onValueCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");

exports.testEventarc = onValueCreated(
  {
    ref: "/test/{id}",
  },
  async (event) => {
    logger.info("Value created:", event.data.val());
  },
);

I have updated firebase-functions and my firebase tools version is 13.22.0
$ npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
$ npm install -g firebase-tools

I have also tried to re-add the project before deploying, using
$ firebase use --add

When deploying my function using the below command, I get no errors.
$ firebase deploy --only functions:testEventarc
...
✔  functions[testEventarc(us-central1)] Successful create operation.
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!

However - the trigger for the function is incorrect.
When navigating to the Google Cloud Console, "Cloud Run functions", and selecting the function "testEventarc" the trigger has these properties:
Eventarc trigger
Name: testeventarc-834306
Event provider: Firebase Realtime Database
Event type: google.firebase.database.ref.v1.created
Receive events from: us-central1
Service account: 1234567890000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Retry on failure: Disabled

Three things seems strange here:

Event type - this should be a v2 function!?
The trigger type is "Unknown trigger" in the cloud console (Cloud Run Functions)
Service account - should this be an eventarc account?
(ie.
serviceAccount:service-1234567890@gcp-sa-eventarc.iam.gserviceaccount.com)

The updated functions I deploy does not respond to any database events, the trigger seems incorrect.
What can I do to remedy this and deploy my upgraded functions?
EDIT:
Does the eventarc trigger need to be in  the same region as the database?
I made some triggers of my own and since my database is in another region than the trigger, trigger creation was not allowed in the UI.
The deploy did not warn or give any error regarding this!
Should the trigger really read: "Unknown trigger"? #confused

Ok, these are my findings!
The eventarc needs the database and triggers to be in the same region!
This is a breaking change from v1 Cloud Run Functions that did not use Eventarc.
I made some triggers of my own and came to this conclusion.
My database was in another region than the trigger, which was not allowed when creating triggers via the UI.
However, the deploy did not warn or give any error regarding this!
Also; It is confusing that the new triggers shows up as "Undefined trigger" and has v1 properties - but the trigger now gets invoked!
Eventarc trigger
Name: testeventarc-834306
Event provider: Firebase Realtime Database
Event type: google.firebase.database.ref.v1.created
Receive events from: us-central1
Service account: 1234567890000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Retry on failure: Disabled

All is not well, though - the trigger is unreliable and / or broken.
It riggers on deploy and triggers on already created nodes erratically.
Have created another question on this topic -->
Google Cloud Run Function v2 - erratic trigger
