Google Cloud Run Function v2 - erratic trigger
PLEASE NOTE: This question is related to my previous question (Deployment of Google Cloud Run Function v2 - trigger not invoked / run), but is regarding a different specific problem.
I am migrating my Google Cloud Run Functions from v1 and Node 12 to v2 and Node 20. So far I have upgraded onSchedule and onMessagePublished triggers with no problem.
When deploing my Cloud Run function with 'onValueCreated' Realtime Database eventarc trigger it seems to act erratic - or at least not as I expect.
This is my code for a test function:
const { onValueCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");

exports.testEventarc = onValueCreated(
  {
    region: "us-central1",
    ref: "/test/{id}",
  },
  async (event) => {
    logger.info("Value created:", event.data.val());
  },
);

I have updated firebase-functions and my firebase tools version is 13.22.0
$ npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
$ npm install -g firebase-tools

When deploying my function using the below command, I get no errors.
$ firebase deploy --only functions:testEventarc
...
✔  functions[testEventarc(us-central1)] Successful create operation.
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!

The trigger for the function does not act as I expect.
When deploying the function it triggers on a random node in /test.
Also, when adding a new data node in /test the trigger acts on several, random, nodes - not just the created data node.
I expect the eventarc trigger to only invoke on newly created nodes in /test/{id} and certainly not on deploy.
Have I misunderstood this trigger or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Instead of asking multiple times basically the same thing just keep one question and add details as needed. I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79083041/deployment-of-google-cloud-run-function-v2-has-the-wrong-trigger

Thank you Puteri! I was of the impression questions should be specific, and not include multiple questions. This is why I created another question - to be clear and specific, and be able to better help others. I could stuff all my questions into one if you think that would make more sense?

@Puteri - I have a solution to this problem that I would like to share. Could you please help me reopen the question to be able to help others with the same issue? KR / K
